# Finder does not open URL to file path

Tags: finder, path, url

in the past, I used to click an URL to a local file in any application (e.g., TextEdit) and the finder or [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com/#/) would open.

An example for such an URL is  `file:///Users/username/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~Keynote/Documents/hgs%20demo.key`, that points in fact to a file on iCloud.

Now, when I click on such a link from say TextEdit (but also other software like in the notes section of a task in OmniFocus), nothing happens anymore. When I paste it into the URL field of a browser, the file does open however.

Is there a way on macOS to set applications that open certain kinds of URLs?

For example, OmniFocus "knows" / is associated with `omnifocus:///...`

→ Can I tell the Finder (or Path Finder) to be associated with `file:///...` (such that it would open a window with the associated path)? Or how can I re-enforce this association?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FWIW - this now seems to work fine in Big Sur. I can open a link to, say, `file:///private/tmp/` using a link in a Rich Text file in TextEdit. It does appear that https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps (linked in the answer below) will allow you to choose what app will respond to `file:///` links. Tested in macOS version 11.4 (20F5046g) [aka 11.4 beta 1]

Answer (score 1):

You can set file associations with [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)(may not work on very new macOS)  or the new replacement [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) but I haven't tested either of these for `file:///`.
I thought file links had been disabled in most OSes in recent years as being inherently insecure.