# How can I make file:// links open the file instead of revealing it in the Finder?

Tags: file, url

I can create a hyperlink within a document in e.g. TextEdit, and set the URL of the hyperlink to `file:///path/to/my-file.txt`.

When I click on the hyperlink, I want my-file.txt to open in the default application for that file type.

Instead, when I click on the hyperlink, a Finder window opens with my-file.txt selected.

This happens with every file type and every application that I've tried.

Is there a way to change macOS's behavior here?

Comment: The application that responds to the file URL is the Finder. You would need to change the application that processes the URL to one that opens the file. It could probably be done with a small Automator application that has a shell script using the `open` command.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407744/finder-does-not-open-url-to-file-path which is kind of the 'opposite' problem but the answer is similar.